# URL Address Forwarding

Tags: web-server, web-hosting

I have a really simple question. I have a website that will only respond to:

**cname.domain.com:1234/something/default.aspx**

On the server side, how do I forward **cname.domain.com:1234** to said address?

P.S. - I am running IIS7

Answer (score 1):

In IIS 7 you be able to do this via the Reverse Proxy and Rewrite modules, I believe.

http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite

http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting

In the site settings, you'll get an "URL Rewrite" icon once installed. From there you can add rules with hostnames and ports specified.